# Bash delete all folders except some

Tags: bash

I have a directory with this structure:

```
main/
    Antispam/res/values/
        strings.xml
        plurarls.xml
        arrays.xml
    Backup/res/values/
        strings.xml
        plurarls.xml
        arrays.xml
```

etc.

`Antispam` and `Backup` have other folders inside, but I do not need those. I just want to have only the `values` folder with the three XML files (`strings.xml`, `plurarls.xml` and `arrays.xml`). How can I do that?

Comment: it's really poor written answer, i'll try my best to answer, but try to improve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

if you run this in the **parent** directory:

```
find .  -regex '.*backup.*'
```

you would have something like this:

```
./backup
./backup/res
./backup/res/value
./backup/res/value/00.xml
./backup/res/value/02.xml
./backup/res/value/01.xml
```

And then you can invert the match by `-not`

```
find . -not -regex '.*backup.*'
```

and of course you can make it more specific with `-type d` and literal `./`

```
find . -type d -not -regex './backup.*'
```

and then do any thing you like with the output

Comment: This work for me:

ale8530@vmi81507:~/Scrivania/APK-Tools-Linux-master/working$ find .  -regex '.*res/values/strings.*'

./WaliLive/res/values/strings.xml ./SystemAdSolution/res/values/strings.xml 

Can you copy this output to another director y? Keeping the same output?

For example

From-->./WaliLive/res/values/strings.xml to ./WaliLive.apk/res/values/strings.xml

Thanks

Comment: @ale8530 **Yes you can** if you mean: saving the output as a simple log/text file. Just use `>` operator to redirect the output, and this `>` will send the output to a file for you, instead of screen. `prompt$ find . > list.txt` . If it is not what you mean, clarify yours please

Comment: I would like to be able to copy the files found in another directory, keeping the start directory for example copy  from-->./WaliLive/res/values/strings.xml to ./WaliLive.apk/res/values/strings.xm

Comment: @ale8530. With this syntax -- find what you want then **pipe** it to **xarge** command to run `cp` command; like: `find .... | xargs -I xxx echo xxx` test this and use **any command you like** in place of `echo`

Answer (score 0):

**PLEASE BACKUP YOU DATA BEFORE YOU TRY!!!**

if you don't care about empty dirs (or you don't care to do everything with one command), i'll do something like:

```
find ! -name strings.xml ! -name plurarls.xml ! -name arrays.xml -type f -delete
```

if you care about empty dirs:

```
find -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir -p
```

Comment: Can use `-delete` rather than `| xargs rm` unless there is a specific reason not to.

Comment: I think you omitted directory names - find requires at least one, before any predicate arguments.  Depending on the Bash settings, `!` can be a metacharacter, so I recommend quoting it.

Comment: it does not require, simply use the current directory as source dir.
+1 for the quoting suggestion, but i never hit the case

Comment: Your script worked, but remain folder empty, is possibile delete?

Comment: @ale8530 i updated the answer, if it works, please flag the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. Basically just find folders excluding the parent folders and send them to oblivion.

```
find main/Antispam/res/values/ '!' -path main/Antispam/res/values/  -type d | xargs rm -f -r $1
find main/Backup/res/values '!' -path main/Backup/res/values  -type d | xargs rm -f -r $1
```

Hope it works for you! :)

Comment: Sorry your script not worked :( thanks for your help

Comment: I have no mistakes, but it does nothing to the folders

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

`ale8530@vmi81507:~/Scrivania/APK-Tools-Linux-master/working$ find .  -regex '.*res/values/strings.*'`

./WaliLive/res/values/strings.xml ./SystemAdSolution/res/values/strings.xml ./SampleExtAuthService/res/values/strings.xml ./DocumentsUI/res/values/strings.xml ./CaptivePortalLogin/res/values/strings.xml ./SoundRecorder/res/values/strings.xml ./ExternalStorageProvider/res/values/strings.xml ./MiuiCompass/res/values/strings.xml ./CloudBackup/res/values/strings.xml ./BackupRestoreConfirmation/res/values/strings.xml ./AntHalService/res/values/strings.xml ./MiuiSuperMarket/res/values/strings.xml ./DownloadProvider/res/values/strings.xml ./VpnDialogs/res/values/strings.xml ./XiaomiAccount/res/values/strings.xml ./SpacesCore/res/values/strings.xml ./CdmaCallOptions/res/values/strings.xml

Can you copy this output to another director
y? Keeping the same output?

For example

From-->./**WaliLive**/res/values/strings.xml to ./**WaliLive.apk**/res/values/strings.xml

Thanks

Comment: **I am not sure to understand what you mean!** But first delete your answer here. Second, please take look at [ask] and [answer]. And if you have any question just **comment** me at my answer.